# How to check a condition in a DRF Serializer and then skip that iteration and go to the next

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer as follows:

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_product(self, obj):
        obj.product = Customer.check_is_product(obj.product_id)
        return obj.product.name

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ['name', 'product']
```

and I have a models.py as follows:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'products'


class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    product_id = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'customers'

    @staticmethod
    def check_is_product(id)
        try:
            product_obj = Products.objects.get(id=id)
        except:
            <if product with that id isn't there, then i wanna skip that iteration in serializer>
        return product_obj
```

Now imagine I have three customers in my Database, out of that, one customer doesn't have any product, then I wanna skip that entire customer's detail in my API response. So my final API response would have a list with only 2 items. Does anyone know how to skip an iteration of the serializer on any condition check?

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the logic within your view.

Option 1: Create a custom view for that type of request.
Option 2: Send a query parameter as a flag for that type of request to your current view. 
Option 3: Just edit the current view with the logic to filter however you want.

Example for option 1, that would return a queryset with all Customers that have a product id greater than 0:

```
queryset = Customer.objects.all(product_id__gt=0)
```

Also, in Customer.product_id, I would recommend switching from models.IntergerField() to models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True).

Edit: More in Depth answer, editing a viewset to get the queryset you want.

```
class CustomerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CustomerSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Customer.objects.all(product_id__gt=0)
        return queryset
```

Comment: We wanna keep it as IntergerField() because of certain system requirements where we do not want the relational integrity of a FK. We can have product ids which may not exist in the product table too.

We cannot create a custom view, since that would mean we need to have a different url for that case. The logic is more complicated, I just created a different use case since I cannot share the actual logic here.
**Is there any way to skip one iteration in serializers?** Basically the requesting client has no idea if the product exists or not.

Comment: You want to skip it in all cases, when using the serializer?

Comment: Not all cases, whenever it goes to the `except`

Comment: Ok, this should be done from the view.  You can edit the current view you have, without changing the URL. Since this is applying to all incoming requests on that URL. I just added option 3 in my answer to make it clear that you don't need to create a new custom view with a new URL. You can use your existing URL and put the logic there.

Comment: I understand your solution, but my requirement needs it to be done from the serializer. Do you have any idea to do that?

Comment: This is my only idea, I don't think it will work, but it is all I got: If the item doesn't exist, set the class Meta fields to an empty list for that instance. Example in the serializer: self.Meta.fields = []